# Common Values in Two Tables in SAS (without Proc SQL)

Tags: sas

I am learning SAS at the moment and I wanted to know how do you join two tables without using any SQL where I need to get only the common values in two tables.

Both tables have a common unique id. Also the tables don't have common variables.
Please don't give any documentation links as I already have and I know merge. I am trying it with an IN operator.

[Table 1 : Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz7Nl.png)

[Table 2 : Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sInsw.png)

Description: The first table has 157 records and the other has 161 records.
I tried searching a solution but didn't get any. Please refer a solution.

Thanks !

Comment: When joining, typically only the unique id (or key) is the common variable on which the join occurs.  What does "I need to get only the common values in two tables" mean to you ?

Comment: Use a data step MERGE and please post data as text, not an image. It's hard to write code or test anything of an image of data. You can add data using the method here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-to-create-a-data-step-version-of-your-data-AKA-generate/ta-p/258712. Documentation for Merge is here: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p15jvywi5avt3cn1bee8r6c33ux1.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: Thanks for people who helped. Mr. Negative Marker Did you even understand my question ? Even I have the documentation and know what is merge my question was to only add only the same observations from both the tables .              Here is my code on your face data new1;
set avik1.total_sales avik1.var2;
merge avik1.total_sales(In=intotal) avik1.var2(in=invar2);
by uniqueid;
if intotal =1 and invar2=1;
run;
proc print data= new1;
run;

Comment: I did understand your question, you got downvoted for not showing any work as per how to [ask] a good question and for posting data as images that no one can work with. FYI - code in comments is a great solution as well.

Comment: I'd almost guarantee that code is wrong as well. If it works, it's by chance. The odds of needing both a SET and MERGE statement in a data step is really, really low. As in almost never.

Comment: Dear Reeza, I wrote a wrong syntax so it didn't work the last time now the code is working fine. Also I asked a question in terms of how to do it ? I never asked for a code. A simple answer saying try "Merge with an In" was sufficient for me !

Comment: Your code is WRONG. You posted it both above and in the comments below the answers. You need ONLY a MERGE statement, not a SET and MERGE. Richard's answer is correct. Did you read the how to ask a good question guidelines linked? What did it say with regards to showing your work?

Comment: Which I found out now ! If I keep a set with merge or not it makes no difference to the code. But I took your suggestion and removed the set statement. Still it works. Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In DATA Step you will want to use the `MERGE` statement and the `IN=` option which sets up flags indicating 'contribution' to the current state of the program data vector (PDV)

```
data want;
   merge
     have1 (in=_from1)
     have2 (in=_from2)
   ;
   by uniqueid; * variable of same name, type and length should be in have1 and have2;
   if _from1 and _from2; * subsetting if;
run;
```

DATA Step is an implicit loop. The MERGE automatically advances reads through the contributing data, synchronizing about the BY variables.

When a DATA Step has no explicit OUTPUT statement, there will be an implicit OUPUT of the values in the PDV when control reaches the bottom of the step. Thus, the if without a then is called subsetting because control only goes past the if (and reaches the bottom for implicit output) when both flags are true (or when data is coming from both tables at a common key value)

Comment: Thanks Richard ! I wrote a new code and it worked ! Thank you ! data new1; merge avik1.total_sales(In=intotal) avik1.var2(in=invar2); by uniqueid; if intotal =1 and invar2=1; run; proc print data= new1; run;